# Identify date ordering of events in SQL (for each group)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to identify the ordering of events in a SQL data table. My data is arranged such that each identifier-date-event combination appears on a separate row. The output should be a single row per identifier, indicating the order in which 3 (and only 3) events occurred, and a flag indicating which of the three events ever occurred. For indicating the order, I only care to know the type of first event and the type of the most recent event. (So, for example, ABC=ADAC, because I'm only interested in the fact that A was the very first thing and C was the very last thing.)

Suppose my data is:

```
CREATE TABLE #ABC
(ID INT NOT NULL,
CODE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
CODE_GROUP VARCHAR(10) NULL)

INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (1,'20000-01-01','APPROVED')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (1,'20001-01-01','DENIED')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (1,'20003-01-01','ON HOLD')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (1,'20002-01-01','APPROVED')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (2,'20008-01-01','DENIED')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (2,'20004-01-01','DENIED')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (3,'20006-01-01','ON HOLD')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (3,'20005-01-01','APPROVED')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (3,'20009-01-01','DENIED')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (4,'20001-01-01','ON HOLD')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (4,'20004-01-01','ON HOLD')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (4,'20007-01-01','DENIED')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (5,'20005-01-01','ON HOLD')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (5,'20008-01-01','ON HOLD')
INSERT INTO #ABC VALUES (5,'20009-01-01','APPROVED')
```

Then the desired output is:

```
ID   RESULT                  EVER_APPROVED   EVER_DENIED    EVER_ON_HOLD
1    'APPROVED THEN ON HOLD' 'Y'             'Y'            'Y'
2    'DENIED'                'N'             'Y'            'N'
3    'APPROVED THEN DENIED'  'Y'             'Y'            'Y'
4    'ON HOLD THEN DENIED'   'N'             'Y'            'Y'
5    'ON HOLD THEN APPROVED' 'Y'             'N'            'Y'
```

Comment: have tried anything or..?

Comment: I'm really stuck. Normally I'd use a SAS data step but no longer have access to SAS. I would guess that I could use MIN and MAX on the date fields to identify the first last events per ID but am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is giving the correct results for your data:

```
with ABCOrdered as
(
  select *
    , FirstEvent = row_number() over (partition by ID order by CODE_DATE)
    , LastEvent = row_number() over (partition by ID order by CODE_DATE desc)
  from ABC
)
select f.ID
  , [RESULT] = case
    when f.CODE_GROUP = l.CODE_GROUP or l.CODE_GROUP is null then f.CODE_GROUP
    else f.CODE_GROUP + ' THEN ' + l.CODE_GROUP
    end
  , EVER_APPROVED = case
    when exists (select 1 from ABC where l.ID = ABC.ID and ABC.CODE_GROUP = 'APPROVED') then 'Y'
    else 'N'
    end
  , EVER_DENIED = case
    when exists (select 1 from ABC where l.ID = ABC.ID and ABC.CODE_GROUP = 'DENIED') then 'Y'
    else 'N'
    end
  , EVER_ON_HOLD = case
    when exists (select 1 from ABC where l.ID = ABC.ID and ABC.CODE_GROUP = 'ON HOLD') then 'Y'
    else 'N'
    end
from ABCOrdered f
  left join ABCOrdered l on f.ID = l.ID and l.LastEvent = 1
where f.FirstEvent = 1
order by f.ID
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a2cf/20).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
;WITH cteMaxMin As
(
    SELECT   
        ID, 
        Max(CODE_DATE+':'+CODE_GROUP) As MaxDt, 
        Min(CODE_DATE+':'+CODE_GROUP) As MinDt,
        Max(Case When CODE_GROUP='APPROVED' Then 'Y' Else Null End) As Apd,
        Max(Case When CODE_GROUP='DENIED'   Then 'Y' Else Null End) As Dnd,
        Max(Case When CODE_GROUP='ON HOLD'  Then 'Y' Else Null End) As Ohd
    FROM     #ABC
    GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT
    ID,
    SUBSTRING(MaxDt, 13, LEN(MaxDt))
    + COALESCE(' THEN '+SUBSTRING(MinDt, 13, LEN(MinDt)), '') As RESULT,
    COALESCE(Apd, 'N')               As EVER_APPROVED,
    COALESCE(Dnd, 'N')               As EVER_DENIED,
    COALESCE(Ohd, 'N')               As EVER_ON_HOLD
FROM    cteMaxMin
```

Answer (score 0):

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT
  ID,
  (SELECT CODE_GROUP FROM ABC WHERE ID = SUB_Q.ID AND CODE_DATE = SUB_Q.MIN_DATE) AS FIRST_EVENT,
  (SELECT CODE_GROUP FROM ABC WHERE ID = SUB_Q.ID AND CODE_DATE = SUB_Q.MAX_DATE) AS LAST_EVENT,
  EVER_APPROVED = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABC WHERE ID = SUB_Q.ID AND CODE_GROUP = 'APPROVED') = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END,
  EVER_DENIED = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABC WHERE ID = SUB_Q.ID AND CODE_GROUP = 'DENIED') = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END,
  EVER_ONHOLD = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ABC WHERE ID = SUB_Q.ID AND CODE_GROUP = 'ON HOLD') = 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
FROM
  (SELECT
    ID,
    MIN(CODE_DATE) AS MIN_DATE,
    MAX(CODE_DATE) AS MAX_DATE
  FROM
    ABC
  GROUP BY
    ID) AS SUB_Q
```

**RESULT:**

```
ID  FIRST_EVENT LAST_EVENT  EVER_APPROVED   EVER_DENIED EVER_ONHOLD
1   APPROVED    ON HOLD     Y               Y           Y
2   DENIED      DENIED      N               Y           N
3   APPROVED    DENIED      Y               Y           Y
4   ON HOLD     DENIED      N               Y           Y
5   ON HOLD     APPROVED    Y               N           Y
```

**EXPLANATION:**

First off, I have a simple sub query called SUB_Q that groups the original data by ID and everything else is done on top of that.

For every ID in SUB_Q, `CODE_GROUP` of the one with min date, gives the first event and `CODE_GROUP` of the one with max date, gives the last event.

For every ID in SUB_Q, count of the any of the three `CODE_GROUP`s if not zero shows that it was ever set to that `CODE_GROUP` during its life cycle.

[SEE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a2cf/28/0)